# Can anyone give me the complete dhyana shloka for Lord Narasimha starting "Manikyadri samaprabham" in Devnagari script?

Tags: vishnu, mantras, shloka

I have the dhyana sloka but probably written down wrongly and I would like to correct the pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

**Narasimha Dyana Slokam - Version-I**

> ॐ माणिक्याद्रिसमप्रभं निजरुचा संत्रस्तररक्षोगणं
>
> जानुन्यस्तकराम्बुजं त्रिनयनं रक्तोल्लसद्भूषणम्।
>
> बाहुभ्यां धृत**चक्रशङ्ख**मनिशं दंष्ट्राग्रवक्त्रोल्लस-
>
> ज्ज्वालाजिह्वमुदग्रकेशनिचयं वन्दे नृसिंहं विभुम्॥

**Narasimha Dyana Slokam - Version-II**

> ॐ माणिक्याद्रिसमप्रभं निजरुचा संत्रस्तररक्षोगणं
>
> जानुन्यस्तकराम्बुजं त्रिनयनं रक्तोल्लसद्भूषणम्।
>
> बाहुभ्यां धृत**शङ्खचक्र**मनिशं दंष्ट्राग्रवक्त्रोल्लस-
>
> ज्ज्वालाजिह्वमुदग्रकेशनिचयं वन्दे नृसिंहं विभुम्॥

**Meaning**: I ever adore the omnipresent Narasimha, He is of the lustre of a mountain of rubies. By his effulgence are the Rākshasa, panic-struck. His two hand rest upon his knees and other two hands hold the wheel and the conch. He has three eyes. His ornaments are brilliant red, flames of fire issuing from his finger and tongue hight up his face. His hair stands on end.

**Note**: In Version-I of Dyana sloka it is **चक्रशङ्ख** whereas in the second version it is **शङ्खचक्र**.